# fuzzy search or phonetic search with hash

Tags: hash, wso2

My business requirements are as follow: I need to be able to do a fuzzy or phonetic search over names. For example, if my database has the string "Müller", I want to get matches for "Muller", "Müler" and so forth.

On top of that, for privacy reasons, I don't want to store the names as plain text. I thought about just storing the hash of the names, and also hashing the search strings and search based on that, but I don't know how to reconcile this with the fuzzy search requirement stated above.

I'll be running this on WSO2 server acessing a MySQL database. Ideally the string match would be done at the dabatase level, but I could also execute some Java library if necessary.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Just got few clarification. Are you going to use WSO2 Application Server or WSO2 Data Analytics Server? How do you are going yo write above logic? As an extension ?

Comment: Hi Tharik, we're using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator, and will access the database through a dataservice to perform the query. I'm still not sure how the data will be inserted on the table, it could be through some java code in a proxy service. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Is it possible to use Stored Procedure to implement the string matching along with md5 function for hashing in your scenario?